# Inject current date into native query of Spring Boot JPA repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

We have the following method in a JPA repository of our Spring Boot 3 app (Kotlin):

```
@Query(
    """SELECT *
        FROM task as t
        WHERE 
        t.end_date IS NULL 
             OR t.end_date >= CAST(NOW() AS DATE)
    """, nativeQuery = true
)
fun findAllCurrentAndFuture(): List<Task>
```

But the reference to `NOW()` makes testing difficult. For example, I've read that we can define a clock bean, but don't know whether that approach can be utilized here.

What can we do here to achieve that we can test against fixed moment in time?

Currently we are using `@DataJpaTest` to test other methods in that repository, so we are hoping for a solution that is compatible with that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the query should be with dynamic param:

```
    @Query(
    """SELECT *
        FROM task as t
        WHERE 
        t.end_date IS NULL 
             OR t.end_date >= CAST(:currentTime AS DATE)
    """, nativeQuery = true
)
fun findAllCurrentAndFuture(@Param("currentTime" LocalDateTime now): List<Task>
```

And in test case you will invoke the repository method with next one argument

```
findAllCurrentAndFuture(LocalDateTime.now())
```

Something like this will be enough.

Comment: Andrei, thank you for working out this answer! For sure this is a solution that works. But I think this is only a second best solution: it introduces a new unnecessary parameter, and with this an unwanted degree of freedom. Also, if I want the calling code to be testable, I need to use LocalDateTime.now(clock) and pass in a Clock dependency. This spreads the clock dependency all over the place. Is there any chance that the repository itself has a clock dependency and uses its own property in the native query?

Comment: The `NOW()`  is sql function and i don`t think that we can mock it in a simple way and pass custom value.

Comment: My idea was to include something like `:{LocalDateTime.now(this.clock)}` in a JPQL query, but this seems not to be supported...